# How do I fix compiler error in c declared but not referenced or never referenced

Tags: c

I looked at a few threads but an answer didn't seem apparent so here goes: example code:

```
uhci_ports_poll( usbuhci_instance_t *soft){
uint64_t class = TRC_HELPER | TRC_MOD_UHCI;
uint16_t reg;
usbcore_instance_t *usbcore = soft->usbcore;
usbhub_instance_t *roothub = soft->roothub;
hub_methods_t           *hub_methods;
uint32_t port_num; 
int event = 0, rc = 0;
```

error: cc-1174 c99: WARNING File =usbuhci.c line 724 the variable "rc" was declared but never referenced.
int event = 0, rc =0
Seems to compile and load fine other than these warnings but can they be fixed?

Comment: Just remove it. It's not referenced, so there is no point in keeping it.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is telling you that `rc` isn't used anywhere.

You can silence the warning by removing `rc`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be removing `rc` but it may be difficult if `rc` is produced during macro expansion or by a code generator.

The traditional way to silence a compiler was casting to `void`. Alternatively one can use `unused` attribute available on GCC and CLANG compilers.

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int b __attribute__ ((unused));
    int c;
    (void)a;
    // will warn about c but not about a and b
    return 0;
}
```